# object dictionary content changed after passing another dictionary to the function

Tags: python, function, dictionary, scipy, python-3.3

Could anyone help me solve this problem. I want to use a function to generate different gamma distributions for me and the only parameter is the shape. Now, I have want to generate two dictionaries: arci and arcj. arci dictionary contains a gamma distribution of shape parameter equals to 2 and arcj dictionary contains a gamma distribution of shape parameter equals to 1. However, when I first get arci, it is right, after I got arcj, arci has been changed to the same dictionary to arcj and there is no code all it to do that. Here is my code:

```
import random
from scipy.stats import gamma
import numpy
arci={}
arcj={}
arc={}

def getdic():
    arci=rundictionary(2)
    print (arci)
    arcj=rundictionary(1)
    print (arci)



def rundictionary(shape):
    arc.clear
    for i in range (101):
        rv=gamma.cdf(i*0.01,shape,loc=0,scale=1)
        arc[i]=rv
    print (arc)
    return arc
```

The rundictionary function is the one I am using to generate the dictionary and the getdic function is the one I am using to pass the input. I am using Python 3.3 version. It will be really appreciated if someone can help me with this.
Thank you!

Comment: Note that you're missing the `()` for `arc.clear` - so that's not being called...

Comment: I have added the () and it becomes arc().clear, then I got the error message.
    arc().clear
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable.

Comment: @user3385478: `dict.clear()` is the method; you'd call `arc.clear()`.